# Geocoding CSV using two fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

First off: While I have a background in GIS, I only did geocoding once, over two years ago, and the tutorials you find online seem highly specific to their own examples. I'm sorry if what I lay out below is excessively vague but that goes to show how in deep I am I suppose.

I have a CSV that has addresses (i.e. 1234 Wall Street) in one field, and the zip in another. I have clipped my roads down to the geography I am using - made of a few zip codes in NYC.

In ArcGIS 10.3, I tried building out an address locator using both dual, and single range locators. I think that the dual range one is correct, based on the fact that the street data has the "left from" and "left to" fields, etc.

The following few things have happened in my trials:

1. The geocoding runs, but 100% of results are unmatched.
2. The geocoding says it has completed, but the status bar never fills.
3. The geocoding apparently completes, and a shapefile of the points is created, but it is not projected or displayed. Have tried reprojecting but to no avail.

Comment: I'm no geocode expert, but it sounds like your question is about building the locator. As you say you dont get a single match (theyre all unmacthed). Can you try the arcgisonline locator to compare against? (yes it costs credits)

Comment: In New York we have a state Geocoding Service that you can use as a GeoCoding service. http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=1278 or download the address point files and join to those.

Comment: @KHbima I know about the online one, but I believe it limits you to 250, where as this is in the thousands and it wouldn't be practical/efficient to break it out like that.